# Integer Logic - Relatively Prime Numbers Proof

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

I could use some help understanding this.

> Let a,b,c ∈ Z. Suppose that (a,c) = (b,c) = 1. Prove that (ab,c) = 1.

I assume that there exist some x, y ∈ Z where (ab,c) = 1 such that abx + yc = 1. I'm unsure about this and I get stuck here. Is this right? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is not true that there exist $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $abx=yc=1$.  What is true however is that there will be an $x,y\in \Bbb Z$ such that $abx + cy = 1$, however this is a result of $(ab,c)=1$ so it may not be assumed until proven.

Comment: I didn't notice the typo I made until you showed that. I did mean abx+cy=1. I apologize! I made the edit to the post.

Comment: @Earthbound27 You still can't assume that $abx + cy = 1$ has a solution, because that is essentially you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it in terms of prime factors. $(a,c)=1$ if and only if $a$ and $c$ share no prime factors, and similarly for $b$ and $c$. The prime factors of $ab$ are those of $a$ and of $b$ with corresponding multiplicities added, so of course $ab$ does not share prime factors with $c$ either.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a,c)=1$, [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity)  says that there exist $x$ and $y$ so that $ax+cy=1$.

If $(b,c)=1$, there exist $u$ and $v$ so that $bu+cv=1$.

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=(ax+cy)(bu+cv)\\
&=ab(xu)+c(ybu+ycv+axv)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(ab,c)=1$